# How to create that logger for Django?

Tags: python, django, logging, django-rest-framework

```
URL: / client /[client_id]/ log / operator
Method: POST
Data:
{
"access_token": "TOKEN",
"limit": 100,
"sort": "asc",
"start_date": "2018-01-01T00: 00: 00Z"
}
OR
{
"access_token": "TOKEN",
"limit": 100,
"sort": "asc",
"offset": "500"
}

Success Response:
{
"result": "ok",
"logs": [
{
"date": "2018-01-01T00: 00: 00Z",
"text": "Log entry"
},
...
]
}
```

Log entry in the format: "message. User: name the name of the operator."

I need to create a request to receive logs of operator activity. Which returns a formatted log of all user actions.

I have an activity application in which there is an OperatorLog model.

```
from django.db import models

from users.models import User
from .constants import ACTIVITY_ACTIONS


class OperatorLogManager(models.Manager):
    """Manager for operator logs"""

    def active(self):
        """Mark object as active"""
        return self.filter(is_delete=False)

    def get_by_user_id(self, id):
        return self.active().filter(pk=id)

    def get_by_client_id(self, client_uid):
        return self.active().filter(client_uid=client_uid)



    class OperatorLog(models.Model):
        """Model for logs"""

        user        = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        created     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        is_deleted  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        action_type = models.CharField(max_length=32,
             сhoices=ACTIVITY_ACTIONS)
        message     = models.TextField(max_length=2048)
        client_uid  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        bitrix_id   = models.PositiveIntegerField()

        # Operator Manager
        objects = OperatorLogManager()

        def delete(self, **kwargs):
            self.is_deleted = True
            self.save()
```

You need a public api (activity / api.py) to register events in other applications,
There is also a file with a list of activity types (constants.py), it should be available in other applications via the import of api.py, you need to output the logs using the serializer (DRF).

constants.py (Sample version)

```
from model_utils import Choices

ACTIVITY_ACTIONS = Choices (
   ('ACTION_REQ_PHONE_VERIFY', 'Request phone verification'),
   ('VALIDATE_PHONE', 'Request phone validation'),
   ('VALIDATE_EMAIL', 'Email validation'),
   ('SET_INTERNAL_VERIFY', 'Set result of Internal verification'),
   ('SET_BANK_VERIFY', 'Set result of Bank verification'),
   ('GET_CLIENT_DATA', 'Request client data'),
   ('GET_SENSITIVE_INFO', 'Request sensitive info'),
   )
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/logging/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the logging library, where you can access various type of log messages 

like-
Error, Debug, Warning or just Information.

You can read more about here: 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html